# How can I update a Table without refresh the entire site razor

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I'm working on a table

I cannot atm update the table without the site refreshing. 
I need a way to easily

Add a row ,Delete a row, Modify a row in a table's content.

my table is build like this.

```
{....}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>ShiftTypes</legend>
    <table class="EditableTable" id="EditableTableShiftTypes">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    #:
                </th>
                <th>
                    ShiftName:
                </th>
                <th>
                    ShiftCode:
                </th>
                <th>
                    Suplement:
                </th>
                <th>
                    ExtraSuplement:
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (BPOPortal.Domain.Models.ShiftTypeView type in Model.ShiftTypeList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @type.ID
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @type.ShiftName
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @type.Name

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @type.Supplement

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @type.OneTimePayment

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button>
                            Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Editor("ShiftName")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Editor("ShiftCode")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Editor("Suplement")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("ExtraSuplement", new SelectListItem[] { new SelectListItem() { Text = "yes", Value = "true", Selected = false }, new SelectListItem() { Text = "No", Value = "false", Selected = false } }, "--Choose--")
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button id="AddButton">
                        Add</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" id="Gem">
        Save</button>
</fieldset>
{....}
```

I've Tried to use Ajax in the following way but it refreshes the entire page.

```
{....}
        var ID= 2;
        $("#AddButton").click(function(){
            var ShiftName= $('#ShiftName').attr('value');
            var ShiftCode= $('#ShiftCode').attr('value');
            var Suplement= $('#Suplement').attr('value');
            var ExtraSuplement= $('#ExtraSuplement').attr('value');


            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("AddData", "ShiftTypesConfiguration")',
                data: { ID: ID.toString(), ShiftName: $('#ShiftName').attr('value'), ShiftCode: $('#ShiftCode').attr('value'), Suplement: $('#Suplement').attr('value'), ExtraSuplement: $('#ExtraSuplement').attr('value') },
                type: 'POST',
                //                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response)
                {
                   function fnClickAddRow() {                       
                      $('#EditableTableShiftTypes').dataTable().fnAddData([
                     response.ID,
                     response.ShiftName,
                     response.ShiftCode,
                     response.Suplement,
                         response.ExtraSuplement,
                         "<button>Delete</button>"]); } 
                    }
            });
            ID++;
        });
{....}


</script>
```

My Method in the Controller that should handle the request.

```
public JsonResult AddData(string ID, string ShiftName, string ShiftCode, string Suplement, string ExtraSuplement)
    {
        TableViewModel tableViewModel = new TableViewModel();
        tableViewModel.ID = ID;
        tableViewModel.ShiftName= ShiftName;
        tableViewModel.ShiftCode= ShiftCode;
        tableViewModel.Suplement= Suplement;
        tableViewModel.ExtraSuplement= ExtraSuplement;


        return Json(tableViewModel);
    }
```

However it doesn't seem to work Now I'm asking For Ideas and ways to make this better/easier/Working

**Edit**:saw a copy past Error

**EDIT2:** I've now changed it slightly I found that I had a error in how my script was running this is the latest. there are still problems but at least now I can see and describe the error.

this is what I changed the script is now

```
 $("#AddButton").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var ShiftName = $('#ShiftName').attr('value');
    var ShiftCode = $('#ShiftCode').attr('value');
    var Suplement = $('#Suplement').attr('value');
    var ExtraSuplement = $('#ExtraSuplement').attr('value');


    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddData", "ShiftTypesConfiguration")',
        data: { ID: ID.toString(), ShiftName: ShiftName, ShiftCode: ShiftCode, Suplement: Suplement, ExtraSuplement: ExtraSuplement },
        type: 'POST',
        //                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            function fnClickAddRow() {
                $('#EditableTableShiftTypes').dataTable().fnAddData([
                 response.ID,
                 response.ShiftName,
                 response.ShiftCode,
                 response.Suplement,
                 response.ExtraSuplement,
                 "<button>Delete</button>"]);
            }
        }
    });
    ID++;
});
```

now with the help of firebug I've seen that the values are back on the page but before I can see them the page is refreshed.

Comment: What does the fnAddData function do? Can you add the code? Also, you might get more info on why it's not working by debugging the js on chrome or firebug.

Comment: fnAddData is a function that should add to the row of the datatable I get it when I'm using the DataTables Jquery plugin. I've been trying the firebug. however it seems to be running just nothing happens. in some cases the entire page is loaded inside the Table. I also get in to the AddData method without problems.

Comment: should you be adding an `event.preventDefault();` on your javascript click function, as surely a click of any button element would reload the page? so you have `.click(function fnClickAddRow(event) { event.preventDefault();`

Comment: I think Kolin and Yasser make good points. Try rolling out your own version of fnAddData basically, shouldn't be too complex. You might also want to change the button to an anchor for example.

Comment: I would like to thanks Kolin and Nieve because of your two comments I am now left with only one problem the Page refreshes and I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Okay I made it work now I won't give myself credits for this because Nieve got me on the right track when you said try rolling out your own version of fnAddData you got me thinking over why and which functions I had. eventually I found that I had a function in the code that was not needed. I removed function fnClickAddRow() {} and now it's working as intended and expected.

so if you make your comment as an answer Then I'll give you some credits for this.

else I'll give the credits to Yasser since he also made me rethink my approach which eventually lead to this result

Comment: As long as you solved the issue while keeping it logged here- that's what really important :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not writing in code here, but here is how you should do it.

On Add/Edit/Delete make an ajax call to your action. In your Action implement your operation (Add/Edit/Delete) and depending on operation completed successfully or failed due to some error, return a true/false flag as json.

Then in the success function `success: function (response){}` of the ajax call, check wether the value returned is a true/false which means success or error.

And then using some jquery you can add a row or delete a row from the table.

Check out these links : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/